# my xmlDictionary its allway (null)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nsdictionary

im trying to get the same value on xmlDictionary and dicionarioXML but, my dicionarioXML its allway (null), any help?

```
@synthesize xmlDictionary;

-(NSString*)buscaDados:(NSData*) dados
{
    NSString * responseContent = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[dados bytes] length:[dados length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError *parseError = nil;
    xmlDictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:responseContent error:&parseError];
    [responseContent release];
    NSString* sucesso=[xmlDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"receitas.total.text"];

    NSLog(@"xmlDictionary: %@",xmlDictionary);

    return sucesso;
}

-(NSDictionary*)trataDados
{
    NSDictionary* dicionarioXML = [self xmlDictionary];

    NSLog(@"dicionarioXML: %@",dicionarioXML);

   return dicionarioXML;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Null means something doesn't exist. What error are you getting back?

```
NSLog(@"Error: %@", parseError);
```

Comment: for my xmlDictionary i have my complete dictionary, from my dicionarioXML just this: 2011-11-03 23:24:15.309 xmlio[2590:b603] dicionarioXML: (null)

Comment: this one "2011-11-04 00:04:29.383 xmlio[2718:b603] Error: (null)"

Comment: That means that there was no data available to read into `xmlDictionary`. That means there's a problem with `responseContent`—either the data you pass in is `null`, the encoding's wrong, or there's a problem with `XMLReader`.

Comment: but, when i have data with the log of reponseContent:2011-11-04 00:14:40.721 Jarbas[2781:b603] xmlDictionary: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<receitas>

Comment: There's not actually any XML content to create a dictionary from. You don't have enough data.

Comment: see my new tile - sorry, my problem its on dicionarioXML, my xmlDictionary its ok :)

Comment: Try using the setter when you're creating it.

Comment: if i make a NSLog of xmlDictionary  on "-(NSDictionary*)trataDados" i will have a null too :(

Comment: Try retaining it when you get it back.